# How to hide a piece of code from a wordpress web page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I installed a plugin called Sociable on my Wordpress website. It displays social media share icons below each blog post, but on my website it's also showing up in the footer. Like here http://amsa.mn/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3
I've been trying to figure out how to remove it from the footer for quite a while, but can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Don't post the same question on different sites http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39062/how-to-hide-a-piece-of-code-from-a-wordpress-web-page

Answer (score 1):

Without looking too closely, my best guess is that the footer text:

`©2012 Америк дахь Монгол Оюутны Холбоо`

is being processed through the `the_content` filter... something like:

`echo apply_filters('the_content', $some_text);`

Typically those social plugins add themselves automatically by hooking into `the_content` filter.